# Create custom file reader using pyspark to read files with newline character in data

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, pyspark, hdfs

I have a delimited file in HDFS which contains newline characters (\n) in data itself and thus while reading with sc.textFile() records split incorrectly. Since data is not quoted I cannot use the multiLine option available in spark.

As a resolution, I am planning to create a custom reader in pyspark so that if any record contains less number of delimiters then the next record will be merged with the same. I am new to spark and looking for suggestions whether this is the correct approach and possible to implement.

Sample data:

```
ID,NAME,AGE,SEX,LOCATION 

 1,Abc,33,M,India

 2,De 

 f,45,F,Australia 

3,Ijk,21,F,Canada
```

Expected output-

```
ID,NAME,AGE,SEX,LOCATION

 1,Abc,33,M,India

 2,Def,45,F,Australia 

 3,Ijk,21,F,Canada
```

(note that the "De f" in the sample data becomes "Def" in the expected output)

Comment: Is your expected output the same as sample data?

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience. I have updated sample and expected  output section of my question.

Comment: Your comment did not answer my question. By logging to edit, one can see that there's a newline between the "De" and "f"', but it's very hard to see in the question body. I've added a comment to the question to emphasize the difference, so others can see.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience. I have updated sample and expected output section of my question.

Comment: what's you data size?

Comment: Avg file size around  3 GB.